# using libGDX/gradle with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, gradle, libgdx

I want to learn to use libGDX to create android apps/games.

I used the installer from the libGDX website to create a new project, installed gradle (on windows10) and am able to build/run my project through command line. (tested desktop version and apk via bluestacks, both work nice)

My problem is now, that Netbeans cannot display my code correctly. It says `cannot access java.lang` at the first line, and things like `cannot find symbol`, `package * does not exist` or `Override is not an annotation type` at the other errors.

I mean, it works somehow, but it's not nice development like that. How can i fix those errors?

[image: Nunch of Errors in NetBeans]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like NetBeans "just" grabbed the folder as a bunch of Java and didn't import the project as a full "gradle project"